# "nudge" a (table)View to use a Navigation Bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

my Context is a tableView controlled by a Navigation Controller. So when i select a row, a new view is pushed by the navigation controller.

Now i want also to "nudge" (like the effect on the start-screen to switch through the App-overview, i hope you know what i mean) to another view (also a tableView, similar to the first View) or back. I tried this by using the touchesBegan and touchesMoved methods, but I wasn't able to realise this. Is there an easier way?

Thank you very much!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want to accomplish, but I assume it's scrolling left and right as on the iPhone home screen. You can achieve this by using a UIScrollView with pagination turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. But my problem is, that I can't control the TableView in the ScrollView. in The IB there is a Navigation Controller, in this a Navigation Bar and a TableViewController and in this Controller a view (named "Overview"), containing a page Control, a Scroll View and in this the Table View (a little bit weird, i know).

Now, my problem is to display the "Overview" View including the cellView and the page Control. By starting my app, there is just the TableView shown, i think this happens because a TableViewController is higher, right? How is it possible to bypass this problem?

Comment: Got nobody an idea or is my problem to opaque?